# jenkins pipline get latest successful commit id and pass in another pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am struggle to get

1.latest successful commit id of github proj (this won't help: echo GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT %GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT%)
2.get this id from one job pipeline and pass to the other jenkins job pipeline

actually at step 2 I have issue
I have tried to save the id in temp file using
rm logfile.txt
echo $commitID | tee logfile.txt
and but jenkins gives an err

getting err
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: logfile for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)

It won't allow to create temp file

also I have checked https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger but unable to use it in multiline or maven proj ( can't understand how to use it )

also tried to inject variable that is commit id I want to store as env.commitID but still unable to save this id anywhere at temp location or as env variable

further after save want to pass to another pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
      timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
  }
  environment {
    def myVariable = "foo"
    py2Ana="DEFAULT"
    SOURCE_CODE_URL = 'https://github.com/himanshukgit/hardwareInventory.git'
    RELEASE_BRANCH = 'master'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Git') {
      agent any
      steps {
        sleep(5)
        // Clean dir
        deleteDir()
      }
    }
    stage('transfer'){
        steps{
        bat """
        @echo off
        echo GIT_COMMIT %GIT_COMMIT% 
        echo GIT_BRANCH %GIT_BRANCH%
        echo GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH %GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH%
        echo GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT %GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT%
        echo GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT %GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT%
        echo GIT_URL %GIT_URL%
        echo GIT_URL_N - %GIT_URL_N%
        echo GIT_AUTHOR_NAME %GIT_AUTHOR_NAME%
        echo GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL %GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL%
        """
        // Checkout branch
        script{
            git branch: "$RELEASE_BRANCH", url: "$SOURCE_CODE_URL"
            echo  "============================================================"
            echo GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT %GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT%
            echo  "============================================================"
            echo "remove temp logfile"
            sh rm logfile.txt
            echo "adding GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT into the file"
            echo  "============================================================"
            echo GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT %GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT%  | tee logFile.txt
            echo  "============================================================"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the `git` (or `checkout`) keywords return the relevant parameters as a dictionary, so you can just keep the returned value of the `git` keyword and through it access the relevant parameters you need.  Something like:

```
node {
    def gitVars = git branch: "$RELEASE_BRANCH", url: "$SOURCE_CODE_URL"
    // gitVars will contain the following keys: GIT_BRANCH, GIT_COMMIT, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT, GIT_URL
    println gitVars
    println "Previous successful commit is : ${gitVars.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT}"
}
```

For the second part you can use the built in `build` keyword for triggering another job (of any type) you have [Multiple Options](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) for controlling the execution.
Here is a simple example:

```
node {
    ...
    build job: 'My_Downstream_Job', wait: true, propagate: true, parameters: [string(name: 'CommitSha1', value: gitVars.GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT)]
}
```

Comment: GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT getting blank as I have updated Git [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) and error look [like](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-35230)

Comment: @Himanshu `GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT` will appear only after the job has been build at least one time successfully. Do you see the other parameters?

Comment: all params are blank

Comment: @Himanshu The error you pointed to is related to the environment parameters, which indeed not work, parameters are available only from the map returned from the git command.